# Give ability to client to upload new photos to his portfolio

Tags: reactjs, upload, frontend, content-management-system, portfolio

As a frontend dev,

I need to create a portfolio website for a client.
But he'd like to upload new photos of his work without having to ask me to do it.

I need to do a grid gallery display.
Each thumbnail is a project. When we click one, a lightbox opens and we can see more photos of this project.

I've been looking into traditional CMS (wordpress, etc..), but i'd like full control of the frontend.
So I checked headless CMS (strapi, sanity, contentful), but it's confusing and I don't know if it can do the job in the end.

Do you have any good and simple solution for this specific demand ?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I finally went with Contentful.
The setup was quite simple, and it gives me the solution i needed.
I can now access my galery database through an api call.
And i can upload new images to database through the contentful webapp, with drag and drop

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).